# static and extern keywords LINK Error C++

Tags: c++, static, extern

I have wrote program to test **static** and **extern** keywords in C++.

**source1.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

static int num;

int main(){
    num = 1;
    cout << num << endl;
    func();
}
```

**source2.cpp**

```
#include "Header.h"

using namespace std;
extern int num;

void func(){
    num = 100;
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

**Header.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <iostream>

void func();

#endif
```

When i compile this program it gives me a link error.

```
 error LNK2001, LNk1120 unresolved externals.
```

What is the reason to causes this Link error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Link Error causes because of **num** variable declared as a *static* variable.

Even though the variable **num** is declared as an **extern** in the source2.cpp file, the linker won’t find it because it has been declared **static** in source1.cpp.

When you declared variable static, **it is local to the file;** it has file scope. That variable is unavailable outside of this file.